# Remove files in Directory B that also exist in Directory A

Tags: windows, command-line, deduplication

[This page](https://superuser.com/questions/1093727/is-there-a-way-to-remove-files-from-a-folder-that-are-in-another-folder/1093830#1093830) has tells how to remove files in Directory B that also exist in Directory A.

I want to use the windows solution but without the copying.

Can someone tell me how to edit the FOR line to just do the compare and then delete? Thank you.

Comment: No. That is a completely different question.

Comment: I would of thought something close to  FOR %%A IN ("%SourceDir%\*.*") DO DEL /Q /F ""%DestDir%\"%%~A"  - This doesnt check if it exists in DEST - it just tries and deletes it - if it fails - then it doesn't exist

Comment: Revised comment:

Thank you, Ross. Unfortunately it didn't work. I need to do some more testing. "The system cannot find the file specified." This was using test directories with the same five files in both directories.

 @ECHO ON

 SET SourceDir=C:\Users\Steve\Desktop\Barnes 330 Discovery Recd 2018-20-15\KV Emails\Source\

 SET DestDir=C:\Users\Steve\Desktop\Barnes 330 Discovery Recd 2018-20-15\KV Emails\SourceDupes\

 FOR %%A IN ("%SourceDir%*.*") DO DEL /Q /F ""%DestDir%\"%%~A"
 pause
 GOTO EOF

Answer (score 0):

`cd /d "c:\dir_B" && for %i in (*)do if exist "C:\Dir_A\%~nxi" echo\Del "%~i" /q /f`

`

**1.** Go to Dir_B folder: `pushd "D:\Dir_B"`

**2.** Use one simple for loop to list yours files: `for %i in (*)do...`

**3.** Test if exist your file in Dir_A folder: `if exist "D:\Dir_A\%~nxi"`

**4.** If last command return true, delete this file in current Dir_B: `del "%~fi"`

- In command-line:

```bat
@(pushd "D:\Dir_B" && (for %i in (*)do if exist "D:\Dir_A\%~nxi" del "%~fi")) & popd
```

- In bat File:

```bat
@(pushd "D:\Dir_B" && (for %%i in (*)do if exist "D:\Dir_A\%%~nxi" del "%%~fi")) & popd
```

- One option using `dir` and operator `&&`

```bat
@(pushd "D:\Dir_B" && (for %i in (*)do 2>nul 2>&1 dir /b "D:\Dir_A\%~nxi" && del "%~fi")) & popd
```

---

```bat
@echo off

set "_SourceDir=C:\Users\Steve\Desktop\Barnes 330 Discovery Recd 2018-20-15\KV Emails\Source" 
set "_DestDir=C:\Users\Steve\Desktop\Barnes 330 Discovery Recd 2018-20-15\KV Emails\SourceDupes"
cd /d "%_SourceDir%" && for %%a in (*.*)do if exist "%_DestDir%\"%%~nxa" 2>nul del /q /f "%%~dpnxa"
```

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[Pushd](https://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html)**

  [√]  **[Popd](https://ss64.com/nt/pod.html)**

  [√] **[For Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)**

  [√] **[For /F Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**

  [√] **[For /R Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html)**

  [√] **[Conditional Execution | Refer `&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**